# Is wifi endpoint a hub?

Tags: networking, wifi

I'm new to networking.I have seen that it's possible to capture packets through wireshark.Having seen it a question arises in my mind.
Is wifi a hub?.I mean,if im able to receive(but ignore by system since those packets aren't intended for me as a client) what another client on the same NAT is receiving doesn't that mean that wifi connection works like a hub since hubs don't filter the destination. 
Sorry for the bad way of asking and explaining!!
And thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Wi-Fi (IEEE 802.11) is a set of protocols that use a shared medium (radio waves). Because the medium is shared, much like the old ethernet (IEEE 802.3) 10BASE-2 coax, all hosts on the medium can hear all traffic on the medium. Neither uses a hub.

A hub is something that was created to allow ethernet to use UTP in the same manner that ethernet could use coax cable. Ethernet has multiple standards to allow it to use different media, but many don't have hubs (specific to a medium and some ethernet standards), and neither does Wi-Fi.